# How to: open article in modal when using firefox

Tags: firefox, joomla2.5

Hi I have a problem with opening article in modal in joomla 2.5 template when using firefox.

When I use crome or ie everyting is fine, but firefox and opera, doesnt work, any idea how to solve this problem?

[link to website](http://nemanja.me/)

Comment: You are definitely going to have to add some of the javascript and html that you are using or no one will be able to help.

Comment: Have you by chance moved your Joomla installation? (For instance, you had it in folder 'X', but later moved it to 'Y'.)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `modal.js` file or the `uncompressed-modal.js` file. There is an `if` statement that sets the condition.

For reference, please, look [here](http://kb.lexo.ch/2012/08/joomla-modal-js-error-in-firefox-when-opening-a-modal-window-message-could-not-convert-javascript-argument-arg-0-nsidomhtmldivelement-contains/).

I hope it helps you.

Try changing those lines. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I put in head of my template code:

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); ?>
```

and create link like this:

```
<a class="modal" href="index.php/article?tmpl=component" rel="{size: {x: 500, y: 400}}">article</a>
```

This all works fine as I said in chrome, ie, safari. But doesnt work in firefox and opera.

on my site you can see example... [nemanja.me](http://nemanja.me)

Comment: The modals open fine for me in Firefox and in Chrome, but I get "An error has occured" in the modal (in both browsers). Not sure if this is the same that you are seeing.

Comment: I can confirm that the Modal boxes do not work in Firefox for me, it pops up with no content, no error. I have found some posts in other forums with the same issue, but no solutions. Seems hit or miss whether people can replicate the problem.